# How do you multiply two generating series?

Tags: haskell, combinatorics

Forgive me if this is better suited to MathOverflow, but my question is probably too simple to put there.

I'm reading S.K Lando's *Lectures on Generating Functions*, which gives this definition of the product of two generating functions **A** and **B**:

`A(s)*B(s) = a0*b0 + (a0*b1 + a1*b0)*s + (a0*b2 + a1*b1 + a2*b0)*s^2 ...`

I understand that the ***s*** is just formal. But - and I know it's obtuse of me - I can't understand how the pattern of terms combining coefficients should continue. If anyone could just extend the definition to one or two more terms, it would probably help me a lot. Many thanks!

For bonus points, an algorithm in Haskell for multiplying two series (represented as lists of coefficients) would be much appreciated too - but it'd be enough for me just to understand the above definition.

Comment: [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/) is a good place for questions which might be too simple for MathOveflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the sum of the coefficient indices is constant in each term. For example `a0*b0 -> 0+0=0`, while `a0*b1 -> 0+1=1` and `a1*b0 -> 1+0=1`.

Recall the [story of young Gauss](http://mathandmultimedia.com/2010/09/15/sum-first-n-positive-integers/), who discovered that by summing a list of consecutive numbers with its reverse, we obtain a list of *constants*. The same trick applies here. We'll just take the first k `a_i` and `b_i` coefficients, reverse the list of `b_i` coefficients, and take the component-wise product of the lists.

Here's some Haskell code to generate the coefficient of `s^i` for `i>=0`, given `i` and the list of `as=[a0,a1,...]` and `bs=[b0,b1,...]`:

```
genCoeff :: [Double] -> [Double] -> Int -> Double
genCoeff as bs i = sum $ zipWith (*) (take (i+1) as) (reverse (take (i+1) bs))
```

To generate all of the coefficients, we simply map the partially applied function `genCoeff as bs` onto the list `[0,1,...]`, i.e.

```
genAllCeoffs :: [Double] -> [Double] -> [Double]
genAllCoeffs as bs = map (genCoeff as bs) [0..]
```

Comment: I guess your `genCoeff` needs a `sum` at the front. Otherwise a nice answer.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Thanks so much, Eric! While I appreciate user5402's contribution without reverse below, I'll choose your answer for its enlightening "Notice that the sum of the coefficient indices is constant in each term." –

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution which doesn't use `reverse`:

```
add [] bs = bs
add as [] = as
add (a:as) (b:bs) = (a+b) : add as bs

mult :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
mult [] bs = []   -- note: [] = 0
mult as [] = []
mult (a:as) (b:bs) = (a*b) : add (add (map (*a) bs) (map (*b) as)) (0:mult as bs)

test1 = do
  let as = [1,2,3]
      bs = [4,5]
  putStrLn $ "as      = " ++ show as
  putStrLn $ "bs      = " ++ show bs
  putStrLn $ "as * bs = " ++ show (mult as bs)
```

Output:

```
as      = [1,2,3]
bs      = [4,5]
as * bs = [4,13,22,15]
```

It was derived from the following identity:

```
(a0+a1*x) * (b0 + b1*x) = a0*b0 + a0*b1*x + b0*a1*x + a1*b1*x^2
```

The correspondences are:

```
a0*b0          <-> a*b
a0*b1*x        <-> map (*a) bs
b0*a1*x        <-> map (*b) as
a1*b1*x^2      <-> (0:mult as bs)
```